# Is there an idiom for "not without disadvantages"?

Tags: idiom-request

> This is a great product, it does, however, come with some disadvantages.

I suppose saying "... but it isn't flawless" etc are equally fine but is there an idiom that could be used here?

Comment: By _disadvantage_, do you mean negative consequences it can bring about by user's consumption or an inherent defect in product?

Comment: inherent defect

Comment: Then I wouldn't buy that product since it's _defective_, and _faulty_, or even _broken_. :-( Some people call it _a piece of junk_ or sometimes _a lemon_. However, since you say the product is great I'd suggest _however, **imperfection is inevitable**_.

Comment: There is the idiom "curate's egg" meaning 'something that is partly good but mainly bad'. But it can hardly meet advertising objectives.

Comment: Is there even an idiom for this? I can't think of any besides @Ahmbro Dude's answer, which isn't really fully an idiom.

Answer (score 2):

I guess, you can use the idiom "pros and cons" in this context.

This is a great product, it does, however, has its own "pros and cons".

[Pros and cons](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/pros-and-cons)

Answer (score 0):

"This is a great product, but every bean has its black..."

Comment: "But there are spots even on the sun" isn't an idiom I'm familiar with, as a native speaker. I'm not sure I'd understand what it means. Some explanation would definitely improve your answer.

Comment: "But every bean has its black" isn't an idiom I'm familiar with, as a native speaker. I'm not sure I'd understand what it means. Some explanation would definitely improve your answer.

Comment: @David Richerby: Interesting. I was sure that it's an English proverb which coincides with the Russian one word for word. So the English equivalent is "Every bean has its black". I've corrected my previous post, thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: It means that everything has its disadvantages.                                           "Ye hae had your ain time o't, Mr. Syddall: but ilka [every] bean has its black and ilka path has its puddle... and it will just set you henceforth to sit at the board end as weel as it did Andrew lang syne." (W. Scott, ‘Rob Roy’ ch. XXXVIII)

Comment: Judging by Ngram Viewer and Google books search results, "every bean has its black", even if once it was in use, nowadays seems to be rather outdated.

Comment: @Yulia I'd understood the phase must mean that everything has imperfections, but only because we're discussing phrases with that meaning. I've literally never heard this phrase before and, if somebody had come up to me in the street yesterday and said it to me, I would have had no clue what they were talking about.